# Web3 not returning promise as expected

Tags: javascript, solidity, web3js

I'm trying to call a web3 function but it is not returning the promise as expected. However, the catch seems to be working fine.

Call to contract:

```
const requestDebenture = async (debentureAmount) => {
    createContractInstance();
    await mGenerousInstance.methods.requestMDebenture(web3.utils.toWei(debentureAmount.toString(), "ether")).send({from: account}, (_, txHash) => {
        if(txHash) {
            notify.hash(txHash);
        }
    }).then().catch();
}
```

Function trying to access the call:

```
requestDebenture = async (e) => {
        const { debentureAmount } = this.state

        this.setState({debentureError: "", isInDebenture: true});
        
        await requestDebenture(debentureAmount)
            .then(async () => {
                await fetchAccountBalances().catch();
                await fetchAccountValues().catch();
                await fetchAccountValues().catch();
                this.setState({isInDebenture: false, debentureShowing: false});
            })
            .catch(() => {
                this.setState({isInDebenture: false, debentureError: "An error has occurred while requesting for your funds"});
            });
    }
```

Comment: `requestDebenture` is used as name for two different functions…!?

Comment: They are in 2 separate files

Comment: That hardly matters. In that second file, you define a function `requestDebenture`, which tries to call a function `requestDebenture`. That name can only mean one thing in that file, not two different things. As is, this function would appear to call itself…?!